# Xamarin -> System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly doesn't work

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, xamarin

I try to include a .csv file in my xamarin.forms project. The problem is, that I think it's only available for all the platforms at once when I use the file as an embedded resource. My assembly only has three methods:

```
Equals()
Load()
ReferenceEquals()
```

But I need `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` to get my code to work.

Do you know how to solve this? Or maybe an alternative?
Btw: I work with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and the trial License of Xamarin.Android/iOS

Edit: I guess it has to do sth. with Xamarin.Forms. A normal Desktop Application hast the Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly(); and it works fine, but I need it in my App :(

Edit 2: I try out this now: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/#Loading_Files_Embedded_as_Resources

Comment: Why do you need `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()` in particular? There are various other ways of obtaining assemblies. Do you know a type within that assembly? If so, `typeof(Foo).Assembly` is probably the simplest approach.

Comment: What do you mean by «doesn't work»? Does it throw? Does it return null? Does it return another assembly?

Comment: it says, there is no definition for "GetExecutingAssembly()" like I said, my Assembly Class has only the three methods mentioned in the question. And no I don't need it in particular, it's just the only way how I found out what could be the solution.

Comment: Is this an instance of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) ?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 11):

Do it this way:

```
var assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
```

Being 'App' the type of your application file.

I've done exactly what you want (reading a csv file) this way.